# Images Pulled in from JSON not displaying in a grid

Tags: css, json, bootstrap-4

guys so I'm pulling in content from a JSON file to populate a grid of images. when the data loads it displays all the images in 1 column instead of in a grid. ideally, i would like a 4 wide image grid. All the CSS for this part of from default Bootstrap 4 values

HTML

```
    <div id="UHD" ng-controller="Content-folders-4K">
    <div id="UHD-frames" class="d-flex">
        <div ng-repeat="friend in UHD" class="row">
            <div id="img-frame" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="/4k/{{friend.name}}.html">
                    <img alt="{{friend.name}}" src="assets/images/4k-thumbs/{{friend.name}}.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <p class="font-weight-bold text-center">{{friend.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current result
[image: current result]

Expected (simulated) result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate the columns instead of the row...

```
<div id="UHD" ng-controller="Content-folders-4K">
    <div id="UHD-frames" class="d-flex">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="friend in UHD">
                <a href="/4k/{{friend.name}}.html">
                    <img alt="{{friend.name}}" src="assets/images/4k-thumbs/{{friend.name}}.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <p class="font-weight-bold text-center">{{friend.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You didn't wrap Your Grid with container and row class 
Follow below example

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"> 1 of 2 </div>         
      <div class="col"> 2 of 2 </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Wrap Your column div with container and row class **

Answer (score 0):

here's the code I used to get it to work.

```
<div id="UHD" ng-controller="Content-folders-4K" class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in UHD" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="{{friend.link}}">
            <div id="tiles" class="tiles">
                <img src="thumbs/111/{{friend.name}}.png" alt="" />
        </a>
        <p class="text-center">{{friend.name}}</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```